# factory_girl has_one association is nil with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations, factory-bot

Good night. I have some problems with my first rails app.
I have two models User and Profile. It have association has_one and belongs_to

**User.rb**

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,:username

   validates :username, presence: true

   has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Profile.rb**

```
 class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :aboutme, :city, :gamelevel, :phone

   belongs_to :user

   validates :user_id, presence: true
   validates :phone, length: { in: 3..12 }
   validates :phone, numericality: { only_integer: true }
 end
```

There are my factories:

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    username     "Valik Leontiev"
    email    "Leontiev@example.com"
    password "foobaryea"
    password_confirmation "foobaryea"
  end

  factory :profile do
    city      "Vladikavkaz"
    gamelevel "M1"
    phone     "8029383744" 
    aboutme   "Hello, my friend!"
    user #association with user
  end
end
```

And I've tested my model with rspec:

**user_spec.rb**
    require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

```
  before do
    @user = User.new(username: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobaryea", password_confirmation: "foobaryea")
  end

  subject { @user }


 describe "profiles associations" do

  before { @user.save }

  let(:profile) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:profile, user: @user)
  end


  it "should destroy associated profile" do
    @profile = @user.profile 
    @user.destroy
    @profile.should_not be_empty  
    Profile.find_by_id(profile.id).should be_nil  
  end

  it "should have not more then one profile" do
    Profile.where(user_id: @user.id).count > 2
    should_not be true
  end
 end
end
```

And I had one failure in "should destroy associated profile" blocks: NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?'. so, how I am undersanding, @user.profile is nil, why association has not building? I've add "user" in profile factories for associate. 
Help me, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is necessarily wrong with your Rails code and `@user.profile` may be perfectly valid.  The `ActiveRecord` class does not have an `empty?` method, which is what the `is_empty` matcher relies on. You should be using some other matcher if you want to test that the `@profile` object is still valid after the associated user is destroyed.

Here's output from a console session that shows the creation of a `User`, the creation of an associated `Profile`, the destroying of the `User` and the impact of the in-memory and saved `Profile`.

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > user = User.create
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
Binds are [#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007ff0b24c1d50 @oid_type=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::OID::Timestamp:0x007ff0b2962440>, @array=false, @name="updated_at", @sql_type="timestamp without time zone", @null=true, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:datetime, @default=nil, @primary=false, @coder=nil>, Fri, 12 Jul 2013 14:12:19 UTC +00:00]
  SQL (10.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 12 Jul 2013 14:12:19 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 12 Jul 2013 14:12:19 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
 => #<User id: 6, created_at: "2013-07-12 14:12:19", updated_at: "2013-07-12 14:12:19"> 
2.0.0p247 :002 > profile = Profile.create(user_id: user.id)
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
Binds are [#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007ff0b41d3060 @oid_type=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::OID::Timestamp:0x007ff0b2962440>, @array=false, @name="updated_at", @sql_type="timestamp without time zone", @null=true, @limit=nil, @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @type=:datetime, @default=nil, @primary=false, @coder=nil>, Fri, 12 Jul 2013 14:12:39 UTC +00:00]
  SQL (3.3ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 12 Jul 2013 14:12:39 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 12 Jul 2013 14:12:39 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 6]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
 => #<Profile id: 4, created_at: "2013-07-12 14:12:39", updated_at: "2013-07-12 14:12:39", user_id: 6> 
2.0.0p247 :003 > user.destroy
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
Binds are nil
  Profile Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 6]]
Binds are nil
  SQL (0.8ms)  DELETE FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = $1  [["id", 4]]
Binds are nil
  SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 6]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
 => #<User id: 6, created_at: "2013-07-12 14:12:19", updated_at: "2013-07-12 14:12:19"> 
2.0.0p247 :004 > Profile.find_by_id(4)
  Profile Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = 4 LIMIT 1
 => nil 
2.0.0p247 :005 > profile
 => #<Profile id: 4, created_at: "2013-07-12 14:12:39", updated_at: "2013-07-12 14:12:39", user_id: 6> 
2.0.0p247 :006 >
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for a comment, but I don't uderstand why @profile is nil?

Comment: In failure I have this comment:   expected: nil
got: #<Profile id: 1, city: "Vladikavkaz", gamelevel: "M1", phone: 8029383744, aboutme: "Hello, my friend!", created_at: "2013-07-13 08:28:39", updated_at: "2013-07-13 08:28:39", user_id: 1>

Comment: I change should_not be_empty to should_not be_nil. I don't understand, how it can be nil and(how I think) have hash at the same time?

Comment: I didn't say that `@profile` is `nil`. I said that `@profile` could be perfectly valid. Instead of testing for `@profile.should_not be_empty`, you should be testing for something like `@profile.should be_valid`, assuming you want to test that the destroy had no impact on the in-memory object. I don't know what expectation the error message you just shared is coming from, but it would make sense if it came from a `@profile.should be_nil`.  If it came from the test of `find_by_id`, then your `destroy` did not properly delete the dependent `Profile` from the database, as should have happened.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect example. I didn't mean that `@profile` is nil from your comment. I've changed my spec file `@profile.should_not be_empty` to `@profile.should_not be_nil`, and I have error: expected:not nil--- got:nil. In your example `profile` is not nil, and in my it is nil. But it must be the same, doesn't it?

Comment: In your previous comment, however, you got a valid `Profile` object reported back. What changed? Can you update your example to show your current spec and the complete error report from rspec?

Comment: I delete `before{ @user.save }` and forgot about it, and have error. I'm sorry, it's my inattention. I changed from my first post only `is_empty` to `is_nil`, and I had error that `Profile.find_by_id(profile.id).should be_nil` is not nil, I change that to `Profile.find_by_id(@profile.id).should be_nil` and all it's ok.

Comment: How I think that `let(:profile) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:profile, user: @user)
  end` create association, and `@profile = @user.profile`  is double it(variable `profile` from factorygirl. But it can't be true, because `Profile.find_by_id(profile.id).should be_nil` was nil . Can you explain why it was different?

Comment: There's still something wrong, I think.  `profile` and `@profile` *should* be identical.  I would do a `puts` on both within your test block after first assigning `@profile` and see what you have.